# Many to Many delete in NHibernate two parents with common association

Tags: c#, nhibernate, many-to-many, cascade

I have 3 top level entities in my app: Circuit, Issue, Document

Circuits can contain Documents and Issues can contain Documents.

When I delete a Circuit, I want it to delete the documents associated with it, unless it is used by something else. I would like this same behavior with Issues. I have it working when the only association is in the same table in the db, but if it is in another table, then it fails due to foreign key constraints.

ex 1(**This will cascade properly, because there is only a foreign constraint from Circuit to Document**)
Document1 exists.
Circuit1 exists and contains a reference to Document1.
If I delete Circuit1 then it deletes Document1 with it.

ex 2(**This will cascade properly, because there is only a foreign constraint from Circuit to Document.**)
Document1 exists.
Circuit1 exists and contains a reference to Document1.
Circuit2 exists and contains a reference to Document1.
If I delete Circuit1 then it is deleted, but Document1 is not deleted because Circuit2 exists.
If I then delete Circuit2, then Document1 is deleted.

ex 3(**This will throw an error, because when it deletes the Circuit it sees that there are no other circuits that reference the document so it tries to delete the document. However it should not, because there is an Issue that has a foreign constraint to the document.**)
Document 1 exists.
Circuit1 exists and contains a reference to Document1.
Issue1 exists and contains a reference to Document1.
If I delete Circuit1, then it fails, because it tries to delete Document1, but Issues1 still has a reference.

DB:
This think won't let upload an image, so here is the ERD to the DB:   http://lh3.ggpht.com/_jZWhe7NXay8/TROJhOd7qlI/AAAAAAAAAGU/rkni3oEANvc/CircuitIssues.gif

Model:

```
public class Circuit
{
    public virtual int CircuitID { get; set; }
    public virtual string CJON { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
public class Issue
{
    public virtual int IssueID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Summary { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Model.Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
public class Document
{
    public virtual int DocumentID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping Files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Model" assembly="Model">
  <class name="Circuit" table="Circuit">
    <id name="CircuitID">
      <column name="CircuitID" not-null="true"/>
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="CJON" column="CJON" type="string" not-null="true"/>
    <bag name="Documents" table="CircuitDocument" cascade="save-update,delete-orphan">
      <key column="CircuitID"/>
      <many-to-many class="Document">
        <column name="DocumentID" not-null="true"/>
      </many-to-many>
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Model" assembly="Model">
  <class name="Issue" table="Issue">
    <id name="IssueID">
      <column name="IssueID" not-null="true"/>
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Summary" column="Summary" type="string" not-null="true"/>
    <bag name="Documents" table="IssueDocument" cascade="save-update,delete-orphan">
      <key column="IssueID"/>
      <many-to-many class="Document">
        <column name="DocumentID" not-null="true"/>
      </many-to-many>
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Model" assembly="Model">
  <class name="Document" table="Document">
    <id name="DocumentID">
      <column name="DocumentID" not-null="true"/>
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Data" column="Data" type="string" not-null="true"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Code:

```
using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    var doc = new Model.Document() { Data = "Doc" };

    var circuit = new Model.Circuit() { CJON = "circ" };
    circuit.Documents = new List<Model.Document>(new Model.Document[] { doc });

    var issue = new Model.Issue() { Summary = "iss" };
    issue.Documents = new List<Model.Document>(new Model.Document[] { doc });

    session.Save(circuit);
    session.Save(issue);
    session.Flush();                
}
using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    foreach (var item in session.CreateCriteria<Model.Circuit>().List<Model.Circuit>())
    {
        session.Delete(item);
    }
    //this flush fails, because there is a reference to a child document from issue
    session.Flush();
    foreach (var item in session.CreateCriteria<Model.Issue>().List<Model.Issue>())
    {
        session.Delete(item);
    }
    session.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the collection before deleting the parent. `delete-orphan` is causing the delete operation to be cascaded to the child because the child is still referenced in the collection. The object does not have the potential to be an orphan until it is derefenced, so that is not checked. [Section 10.11 in this documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive) explains it well but it's still confusing. As I understand it, `delete-orphan` has two possible outcomes when the parent is deleted:

1. If the child is still referenced in the parent's collection then it is deleted.
2. If the child is no longer referenced in the parent's collection then it is deleted if it is an orphan, i.e. has no other references.

I think this will work as desired:

```
    using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        foreach (var item in session.CreateCriteria<Model.Circuit>().List<Model.Circuit>())
        {
            item.Documents.Clear();
            session.Delete(item);
        }
        session.Flush();
        foreach (var item in session.CreateCriteria<Model.Issue>().List<Model.Issue>())
        {
            item.Documents.Clear();
            session.Delete(item);
        }
        session.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: The added lines:  
item.Documents.Clear();  

Do not actually cause a difference in behavior. The problem is not that the lines do not get delete properly when dealing with a single entity. The problem is the second entity that has a relationship to the document entity, which is still holding a reference. The suggestion suffers from the same problem as the sample that I provided.

Comment: What is the problem with the second entity -- it's not clear from your question.

Comment: Using the DB Model as a reference: http://lh3.ggpht.com/_jZWhe7NXay8/TROJhOd7qlI/AAAAAAAAAGU/rkni3oEANvc/CircuitIssues.gif

Assume:
DocumentID: 1
IssueID: 1

Comment: The problem is that it appears that Nhibernate only looks at a single relationship when determining what is an orhpan and what is not. I have tried to add more detail to the original post.
Does this make it more clear? I am new to the site and am trying to provide as much detail as I can and will provide whatever is needed to be explicit.
Thanks!

Comment: So at this point, my research says this is just a limitation of Nhibernate.

Comment: I don't think that's the case but I unfortunately I don't have time to set up a project to reproduce this.

Comment: Is this what you're running into? I believe I had the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621328/problem-with-nhibernate-not-detecting-other-associations-when-all-delete-orphan-i/3621931#3621931